# Char Array output - C++

Tags: c++

Apologies if I missed another thread, I looked through the recommended and none are quite like what I am experiencing.  I am trying to display the alphabet in both upper-and-lower-case letters. Before I commit to the full thing I wanted to test with just a few:

```
int main()
{
    char *letters[79] = { "Aa ","Bb ","Cc ", "/0"} ;
    int pause;
    cout << "Letters are: " << letters << endl ;
    cout << "Continue (Y or N)" << endl ;
    cin >> pause;
    cout << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

When I attempt to compile this has been the result:

[console output of above code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SL0uu.png)

What I cannot understand is why I am getting what appears to be a hex output on those letters instead of the letters themself.

Comment: Why are you using arrays? Why are you using `char*` instead of `std::string`? To learn, or because you think that's the best approach? Knowing this helps others help you. :)

Comment: Learning, I am still in college for this and its pretty much my third week, this is the very edge of an assignment using arrays and pointers.

Comment: letters refer to the memory address of the first element of the array. If you want to print the elements , then use indexes like letters[0] for first element , letters[1] for second element and so on.

Comment: Side note: what't mthe purpose of `"/0"`? My crystall ball tells me it does not what you thinkt it does.

Comment: @MichaelWalz a secondary book I am using said to use it when I am using characters in an array to ... its considered a null character.

Comment: @DeSa that' what I thought. It's `\0`, not `/0`. But `"\0"` is pretty useless anyway, because strings (including zero length strings) are automatially terminated by a NUL character). So you can just write `""`.

Comment: @MichaelWalz ah, thank you.  I thought it seemed pretty strange. Thanks again!

Comment: It appears the answers below have gotten what I wanted to appear to appear ... however, now I seem to have a "unhandled exception thrown write access violation _first was nullptr" pop up during debugging

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed to mention array index `letters[0]`

Try this:

```
char *letters[79] = { "Aa ","Bb ","Cc ", "/0"};
cout  << "Letters are: " << letters[0] << endl;
```

output:

```
Letters are:  Aa
```

Or in loop like this :

```
char *letters[79] = { "Aa ","Bb ","Cc ", "/0"};
for(int i=0; i<sizeof(*letters); i++)
    cout  << "Letters are: " << letters[i] << endl;
```

output:

```
Letters are:  Aa  

Letters are:  Bb  

Letters are:  Cc  

Letters are:  /0
```

Answer (score 0):

Your console output shows the address of the ***letters***, because you are telling it to print the pointer, which points to a memory address. You need a loop to iterate over it. The rest is [pointer arithmetic](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_pointer_arithmetic.htm).

Also, "Aa" is not a char type, but "A" and "a" are. So, you should also define them separately; otherwise, it is very likely that you get a compiler warning. Please note that the last character should be "\0", not "/0". If you could try this:

```
int main()
{
    char *letters[79] = { "A","a","B", "b", "C", "c", "\0"} ;
    int pause;
    cout << "Letters are: ";
    for(int i = 0; i < 79; i++){
        cout << letters[i];
    }
    cout << endl << "Continue (Y or N)" << endl ;
    cin >> pause;
    cout << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Then, the output is:

```
Letters are: AaBbCc
```

Comment: Thank, between you, aghilpro, and Micheal up above this has come along way ... now, to solve the "unhandled exception thrown write access violation _first was nullptr" error that has popped up.